# Cisco 93180LC nxos 10.2 license question

Tags: cisco-nx-os

We have a pair of cisco n9k-c93180lc-ex with nxos 9.3.13 and we want to upgrade them to nxos 10.2. it seems cisco changed the licensing model in nxos 10.2 to smart and we should connect to internet, i want to know can we use the features such as bgp in honor mode like as nxos 9.3.13 ?